# Specified cast is not valid

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I tried all my best to cast the value but some how i keep getting this exception. Hope some one will guide me in the right path.

Here is my code

This type from service

```
 public enum ChannelCodeType {

    /// <remarks/>
    A1,

    /// <remarks/>
    A2,

    /// <remarks/>
    A3,

    /// <remarks/>
    A4,
}
```

in my winform i have a list box that generate all these channels ,i try to cast the selected channels in the list box and pass it to the channel type but it gives me a hard time.

```
 ChannelCodeType[] ChannelCodes;
ChannelCodes=lbSearch.SelectedItems.ToString().Cast<ChannelCodeType>().ToArray();
```

then i tried like below also failed

```
string[] destination = new string[lbSearch.Items.Count];
        lbSearch.Items.CopyTo(destination, 0);
        ChannelCodes = destination.Cast<ChannelCodeType>().ToArray();
```

in both way it keeps complaining about cast is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ChannelCodes = destination.Select(e => (ChannelCodeType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ChannelCodeType),e)).ToArray();
```

Try something like the above.

The problem with your current approach is that you can't cast a string to an enum directly. You have to parse it.

Comment: ,after tried with your suggestion it throws new exceptiion " cann't implicitly convert Object[] type to ChannelCodeType[].